# Flutter Light and Dark mode not updating provider

Tags: flutter

I have a controller for theme changing like this

```
class ThemeProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  ThemeMode systemThemeMode = preferences.getBool(Keys.isDarkMode) == null
      ? ThemeMode.light
      : preferences.getBool(Keys.isDarkMode) == true
          ? ThemeMode.dark
          : ThemeMode.light;

  bool isDarkMode =
      SchedulerBinding.instance.window.platformBrightness.name == "dark"
          ? true
          : false;

  toggleTheme(bool isPro) {
    if (isPro) {
      isDarkMode = !isDarkMode;
      preferences.setBool(Keys.isDarkMode, isDarkMode);
      systemThemeMode = isDarkMode ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my main.dart

```
return MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => UserController()),
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => TeamsController()),
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => MatchListController()),
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => NewsProvider()),
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => ThemeProvider()),
    ],
    builder: (context, _) {
      final themeProvider =
          Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context, listen: false);
      return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: LightDarkTheme.lightTheme,
        darkTheme: LightDarkTheme.darkTheme,
        title: 'CricketR Plus',
        themeMode: themeProvider.systemThemeMode,
        home: LoginScreen(),
      );
    });
```

I am updating value by toggleTheme and I can see its updating by print but theme is going to light to dark. But If I toggle and restart my app then its working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

With `Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context, listen: false)` you specify that you don't want to listen to changes in the provider.

Instead, use this when set `themeMode` within `MaterialApp`:

```
themeMode: context.watch<ThemeProvider>().systemThemeMode,
```

Comment: Tried this also but not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Consumer widget for that
wrap your MaterialApp in it. Then, you can call the ThemeProvider inside the Consumer and update the themeMode of the MaterialApp whenever the theme is toggled.

Here is an example

```
return MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => UserController()),
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => TeamsController()),
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => MatchListController()),
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => NewsProvider()),
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => ThemeProvider()),
    ],
    builder: (context, _) {
      return Consumer<ThemeProvider>(
        builder: (context, themeProvider, child) {
          return MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            theme: LightDarkTheme.lightTheme,
            darkTheme: LightDarkTheme.darkTheme,
            title: 'CricketR Plus',
            themeMode: themeProvider.systemThemeMode,
            home: LoginScreen(),
          );
        },
      );
    });
```

Comment: Tried this also but not working.